# gradle Integration test code can't see classes defined in unit test

Tags: unit-testing, gradle, integration-testing

I defined an integration test suite for our gradle build like this:

```
testing {
    suites {
        integrationTest(JvmTestSuite) {
            dependencies {
                implementation project
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And to get my integration tests to see the test dependencies, I added these configurations:

```
configurations {
    // This configuration allows us to define spring-devtools as available only in dev mode
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
    integrationTestImplementation.extendsFrom testImplementation
    integrationTestRuntimeOnly.extendsFrom testRuntimeOnly
}
```

That works except for one problem:  My integration tests cannot see utility classes defined in the unit tests (src/test).  I've searched for a solution but I cannot find out how to get the integration tests to have the unit tests on the classpath.

Can someone people tell me how to configure Gradle for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [java-test-fixtures plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:java_test_fixtures) was designed to share common code between test suites, even across project boundaries. I'd suggest to use it for your test model and utility classes. See the linked documentation on how to configure it.